# C# reflection get object from type

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a Type object.
I want to get the object isntance from this type. (just to use the ToString() method from this object).
see:

```
    public class P
{
    public string s;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        P p = new P();
        p.s = "foobar";
       Type t = p.GetType();
       P p2 = ((t.ToObjet()) as P).s;

       Console.WriteLine(p2.s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

[Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx) is what you want.

```
Type givenType;
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(givenType);
...
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(givenType) as GivenType;
```

**EDIT:** Based on your edits, the extension method on `Type` you want (`ToObject`) is effectively the code above.  It must create a new one because you can't be certain the source object still exists and even with the type, you could hit a scenario where that type has multiple instances.

Comment: this doesn't work because this will create a NEW object and I want the old one.

Comment: @Rodolfo:  wait.  You want the object that was used to populate the Type object?

Comment: @Rodolfo: how can you be sure that an instance of your class already exists?

Comment: @Rodolfo: The .NET runtime doesn't keep track of all objects ever created. If you want to get a certain "old" object, you should take care to remember a reference to it somewhere, so that you can retrieve it later. In any case, it would help a lot if you described your problem in a bit more detail.

Comment: ... or that there's only one?

Comment: @Austin: the OP clearly want *the same instance* back. `CreateInstance` is not going to do that.

Comment: @Fredrik: the OP edited the question; previously is was just "how to get an object from type", for which `Activator.CreateInstance` was a correct answer.

Comment: @Vlad: I saw the edit, but I found that pretty clear even before (it said *"the object instance"*, not *"an object instance"*). But, yes, it was made more clear with the edit.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the instance back. The type is shared between all the instances, so what you want is impossible.

For example: if you know that something is an integer, you don't know which exactly value it has. (Integer is your type, value is a concrete instance.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that. One reason is that `GetType` will return the same `Type` instance for all instances of the same type.

You can test this like so:

```
// this will print "True"
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals("one".GetType(), "two".GetType()));
```

Calling `GetType` on those two different string instances returns the same `Type` instance, so it is clearly impossible to get one of them back based only on that `Type` instance.

Comment: but from type you could call a getMethod("something").

Comment: @Rodolfo: But in order to _call_ the method which you get by `GetMethod`, you need an instance anyway.

Comment: @Rodolfo: As @Vlad said, you need an instance to do that (unless you want to call a `static` method, then you need no instance, of course)

Comment: Yes, and you will get a `MethodInfo` and its `Invoke()` method requires an instance if you are going to call an instance method.